# How to remove the "read and change all your data..." warning for Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have created a Chrome extension and published it to the Chrome Web Store.  I noticed with my initial version that when a user tried to install it they would get the warning that my extension could "read and change all your data on the websites you visit".   I've changed and republished my extension so that I don't think that warning should be displayed, but it still gets displayed.  Based on the information at https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permission_warnings I don't think that message should be showing up.   Below is what is in my manifest.json file.  Any suggestions for how to make the warning go away?

```
{
  "name": "Screen Recorder",
  "description": "Record a video of your computer screen",
  "version": "0.4",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "icons": {
     "16": "icon.png",
     "128": "icon.png"
  },
  "background": {
       "scripts": [ 
          "background.js",
          "ourrecorder.js"
       ]
  },
  "browser_action": {
       "default_icon": "icon.png", 
       "default_popup": "receiver.html"
  },

  "permissions": [
    "desktopCapture",
    "tabCapture",
    "notifications",
    "unlimitedStorage"
   ]
}
```

Comment: Must be the tab capture. Just replace it with the desktop capture api.

Comment: Switch to [optional permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permissions), duh.

Comment: Daniel Herr was correct.   Removing the "tabCapture" permission solved the problem.